# Member function syntax works on msvc but rejected by gcc and clang

Tags: c++, member-functions

I wrote the following program that is accepted by msvc but both gcc and clang rejects it.

```cpp
struct C
{
    void Bar(int);
};
int main()
{
    void (C::*ptr)(int) = &(C::Bar); //compiles with msvc but both gcc and clang rejects this
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PdYsv4T3n)

Gcc says:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:7:32: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void C::Bar(int)'
    7 |     void (C::*ptr)(int) = &(C::Bar); //compiles with msvc but both gcc and clang rejects this
      |                                ^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Just for kicks, try `&C::Bar`, not `&(C::Bar)`

Comment: I can't say for certain because I don't know the grammar off the top of my head but `void (C::*ptr)(int) = &C::Bar;` works with [all three compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/b8h4YWcEz) and is the form I've always seen and used when creating member function pointers.

Comment: All implementations are ok with `void (C::*ptr)(int) = &C::Bar;` but I don't see the diff in precedence. I'm gonna cry ...

Answer (score 4):

This is a msvc bug. The standard explicitly forbids this in [expr.unary.op](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.unary.op#4):

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its operand is a qualified-id **not enclosed in parentheses**.
>
> [Note 4: **That is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is enclosed in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member”.**
> Neither does qualified-id, because there is no implicit conversion from a qualified-id for a non-static member function to the type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of function type to the type “pointer to function” ([conv.func]).
> Nor is &unqualified-id a pointer to member, even within the scope of the unqualified-id's class.
> — end note]

(emphasis mine)

This means that the program is ill-formed and msvc is wrong in accepting the code.

Here is the msvc bug:

[MSVC accepts invalid program involving member function pointer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-program-involving-m/10376896)

Comment: Ah, nice. I can stop crying now!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Haha, C++ never ceases to surprise!

Comment: @TedLyngmo • The *C* in **C++** stands for Crying, and why it's the world leader in Tears Driven Development.

Comment: @Eljay ❤️ One of these days I'm going to understand what I'm doing all day - or not - what fun would that be? :-)